# my php variable is causing a mailchimp api error

Tags: php, mysql, variables, mailchimp

I am pretty new at this so here is my franken code.

My goal is have the new person added to mysql update to my mailchimp list. I'm doing this a step at a time while I learn.

The mysql code will return the row that I want if i use "echo"
The mailchimp api will update the list when manual enter the values into the code.
However if I put them together I get an error says that a ',' was expected.

My guess is that it has to do with the [0] part of the variables $row[0]

Thanks for the help.

```
<?php
//mysql code

mysql_connect('localhost', '****', '****') or die( mysql_error() );
mysql_select_db('cla-constituents');



$result = mysql_query("SELECT per_FirstName, per_LastName, per_Email FROM person_per WHERE per_FriendDate > '2013-03-18'");
if (!$result) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

//echo $row[0]; // first name
//echo $row[1]; // last name
//echo $row[2]; // email




/**
This Example shows how to run a Batch Subscribe on a List using the MCAPI.php 
class and do some basic error checking or handle the return values.
**/

require_once 'inc/MCAPI.class.php';
require_once 'inc/config.inc.php'; //contains apikey

$api = new MCAPI($apikey);
$listId = "****3";



$batch[] = array('EMAIL'=>$row[0], 'FNAME'=>$row[1]), 'LNAME'=>$row[2]);
$batch[] = array('EMAIL'=>'boss2.man@email.org', 'FNAME'=>'Me2', 'LNAME'=>'Chimp2');

$optin = False; //yes, send optin emails
$up_exist = true; // yes, update currently subscribed users
$replace_int = false; // no, add interest, don't replace

$vals = $api->listBatchSubscribe($listId,$batch,$optin, $up_exist, $replace_int);

if ($api->errorCode){
    echo "Batch Subscribe failed!\n";
    echo "code:".$api->errorCode."\n";
    echo "msg :".$api->errorMessage."\n";
} else {
    echo "added:   ".$vals['add_count']."\n";
    echo "updated: ".$vals['update_count']."\n";
    echo "errors:  ".$vals['error_count']."\n";
    foreach($vals['errors'] as $val){
        echo $val['email_address']. " failed\n";
        echo "code:".$val['code']."\n";
        echo "msg :".$val['message']."\n";
    }}
?>
```

Comment: *Obligatory:* The `mysql_*` functions will be [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: Looks like you have an extra parenthesis after `$row[1]`: `$batch[] = array('EMAIL'=>$row[0], 'FNAME'=>$row[1]), 'LNAME'=>$row[2]);`

Comment: So i'm a total noob. I will change but can you tell me the exact command to use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$batch[] = array('EMAIL'=>$row[0], 'FNAME'=>$row[1]), 'LNAME'=>$row[2]);
```

Change to:

```
$batch[] = array('EMAIL'=>$row[0], 'FNAME'=>$row[1], 'LNAME'=>$row[2]);
```

Comment: Thanks, how do you guys see this stuff. I read that 3 times before I could spot a difference.

Comment: Anytime! Sometimes it really is as simple as just needed another pair of eyes to look at it. No worries, it happens to us all :)